# how can i set starting position of a tabs in swipe Tabs for removing there scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a phonegap app for using swipe tabs i have four tabs and every tab have a specific div getting dynamic data using Ajax. the tabs simply work fine. but there have a problem in scroll bar. suppose i have in First tab page then Ajax call and get data from URL. suppose he get 100 data from the URL now for seeing the last data i use scroll the page. The problem is here now at this time i swipe First Tab to Second Tab then Second Tab use the scroll of first Tab page and that are also show in last of the page. I don't know i can explain this so i add some snapshot of this problem. Any one please help me. Thanks. I have no reputation for post the images so i add my code for swipe.

```
My index.html


<div class="tabs"> <a href="#" class="active">Orders</a> <a href="#" >Quotes</a> <a href="#">Closing</a> <a href="#">Encompass</a></div>
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-style">
                <div class="content-slide">
                    <ul id="order-list" style='padding:0px; margin-top:68px;'>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-style">
                <div class="content-slide">
                    <ul id="quote-list" style='padding:0px; margin-top:68px;'>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-style">
                <div class="content-slide">
                    <ul id="closing-list" style='padding:0px; margin-top:68px;'>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-style">
                <div class="content-slide">
                    <ul id="encompass-list" style='padding:0px; margin-top:68px;'>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i use the reference of swipe tabs this [link](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php) Tabs with feedback demo

here is my swipe css

```
.swiper-container {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
-o-backface-visibility:hidden; 
backface-visibility:hidden;
/* Fix of Webkit flickering */
z-index:1;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
position:relative;
width:100%;
-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform, left, top;
-webkit-transition-duration:0s;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform, left, top;
-moz-transition-duration:0s;
-moz-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
-moz-transition-timing-function:ease;
-o-transition-property:-o-transform, left, top;
-o-transition-duration:0s;
-o-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
-o-transition-timing-function:ease;
-o-transform:translate(0px,0px);
-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform, left, top;
-ms-transition-duration:0s;
-ms-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
-ms-transition-timing-function:ease;
transition-property:transform, left, top;
transition-duration:0s;
transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
transition-timing-function:ease;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
float: left;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
/* IE10 Windows Phone 8 Fixes */
.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
-ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.swiper-wp8-vertical {
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
}

.swiper-container {

}
.swiper-slide {

width: 25%;

}
.swiper-slide-active {
/* Specific active slide styling: */
}
.swiper-slide-visible {
/* Specific visible slide styling: */   
}

.swiper-pagination-switch {
/* Stylize pagination button: */    
}
.swiper-active-switch {
/* Specific active button style: */ 
}
.swiper-visible-switch {
/* Specific visible button style: */    
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS here?

Comment: css good, putting example jsfiddle better.

Answer (score 4):

css

```
.swiper-slide {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image: Working woth demo on site]
[image]

Comment: how did you resolve it, if it's not the same way I did? It's always helpful to include that, so other readers have that to reference.

Comment: was it swiper-container { overflow: hidden; }?

Comment: i use .swiper-slide {
    overflow-y: auto;
} in my css code and that's relay work perfect

Comment: so you can click the green check>

Comment: lol. seriously, man. These fake internet points are important!